# Excel vba for automating website

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm a beginner in excel vba.
I'm trying to click html element by id but it is not working

This is my code for my website...
I navigated to website and put user ID and password. Thats ok,just like i mentioned in code they all working but after i logged in (i attached an imaged link),when i inspect the html that i want to click, it shows like this...

[HTML Element Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cER2l.png)

```
Sub WebAuto()

Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

Dim inputCollection As HTMLElementCollection

Dim i As HTMLInputElement

Dim obj As Object



objIE.Visible = True


objIE.Navigate ("***")      'for example

Do

DoEvents

Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

objIE.Document.getElementById("uid").Value = "***"             'user ID typed
objIE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "***"        'pw typed


With objIE.Document

    Set obj = .getElementsByTagName("input")
    'Debug.Print TypeName(aeiou)

    For Each i In obj

        If (i.getAttribute("value") = "Log In") Then
            i.Click
            Debug.Print "Logged In"
            Do
            DoEvents
            Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

        End If

    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

[HTML Element to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrXEJ.png)

This is my very first question on Stack Overflow, so please forgive me if i made any mistakes. Thank you all..

Comment: Can you supply an URL or more HTML? Is the element within a form/frame/iframe tag? And what does not working mean? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it? What is the expected result? Is there associated javascript?

Comment: Did you ensure that the webpage is fully loaded? If the webpage hasn't loaded then the element probably doesn't exist yet.

Comment: ^^ Please show more of your code as well that will help so some extent to tell if basic waits for page loading have occurred.

Comment: As K. Davis says, this is likely a matter of whether the elements are loaded.

Comment: Dear @QHarr, i m so sorry about my incomplete question,like i said i m a new to both vba and stack overflow, I attached two images for HTML Element codes and website page, its my company website, if my question still incomplete. plz let me know.  sorry again for being unresponsive...thanks

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs ,i think its fully loaded, i used do while loop to make sure the web page is fully loaded. plz check my question...thanks

Comment: The element has an id, have you tried targeting that?

  objIE.Document.getElementById("siteDetails").Click  . I see you mention that you have tried clicking by id. Is that the id you used? And did the accepted answer solve your problem?

Comment: Then if your webpage is fully loaded as you say it is, then the only other thing I can think of is that your element is in an iFrame. These, in a nutshell, are treated like a separate document then your main HTMLDoc. So when you use `ieObj.document` you are not referring to the iframe’s document. We will need to basically see the entire HTML tree in order to confirm for you though

Comment: Dear@QHarr,i've already tried objIE.Document.getElementById("siteDetails").Click but it didnt work,i got an error message like "Run-Tim error '70' (Permission denied)",i still working on accepted answer, thats the id i used(siteDetails). Did i do something wrong sir?

Comment: Dear@K.Dᴀᴠɪs, i want to provide full html tree for you, i found that i can only copy one html element code  from Chrome(inspect element), how do i copy whole tree from chrome, thz for your advice sir...Cheers!!!